# Hyperledger Fabric: How to catch transaction errors with chaincode in JS/Node?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using the following dependencies in my JS/Node based chaincode:

- "fabric-contract-api": "~1.4.0",
- "fabric-shim": "~1.4.0"

to query my ledger. The code looks something like:

```
'use strict';

const { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');
const shim = require('fabric-shim');

...

class ThingsChainCode extends Contract {

    async queryThing(ctx, id) {
        const thingAsBytes = await ctx.stub.getState(id);
        if (!thingAsBytes || thingAsBytes.length === 0) {
            throw new NotFoundError(`${id} does not exist`);
        }
        return thingAsBytes.toString('utf8');
    }

    async updateThing(ctx, id, jsonData) {

        await ctx.stub.putState(id, Buffer.from(jsonData));
        var succMesg = `${id} updated`;
        retVal = shim.success(succMesg);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly from time to time (when there are concurrent reads/writes within one batch) transactions are marked as invalid by the state validator. The Reason code states "MVCC_READ_CONFLICT". The question at this point is **not** whats the cause of these errors. Instead i would like to catch the errors. As in go based chaincode this seems to be pretty simple: [Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode throws MVCC_READ_CONFLICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51722254/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-throws-mvcc-read-conflict)

There is no execption thrown or error returned in JS. I didn't found any code examples were there is further error handling: https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/index.html

So the question is how to catch transaction errors with JS/Node based chaincode?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVCC_READ_CONFLICT occurs at validation time, not during proposal simulation which is when your chaincode executes. So in that respect it doesn't matter which language you write your chaincode implementation in.

To determine if a transaction fails validation and thus gets marked invalid, you need to listen for transaction events and check to see the state of that transaction that tried to be committed. I'm assuming you would use node as your client side language here and would recommend using the fabric-network npm package, which has transaction event handling built in for you. When do you submitTransaction on a contract instance, if the transaction fails to commit due to say an MVCC_READ_CONFLICT then it throws an error.

Would suggest you review the various hyperledger fabric documents (eg https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/developapps/application.html) and hyperledger fabric samples which use the fabric-network api (sometimes referred to as the high level api as opposed to the low level api)